# Affine Transformation and Continuous Deformation

Tags: geometry, transformation, visualization

How do these two concepts relate?

Thus far I have a (what I think is a) good intuitive idea of a continuous deformation- the visual basically looks like the boundary being stretched so that it never passes across a hole in the main body.

But then looking into affine transformations of conics there seems to be potential that the two relate.

Is one a more powerful form of the other?
Completely different?

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614807/35416) may give you an idea of how one can obtain an affine transformation as the result of a continuous deformation. Orientation-reversing affine transformations aren't covered by that, though.

Comment: Thank you sire.  Will have a read.

Comment: Original poster likely has a continuum mechanics in mind. In mathematics, there are no specific relation between the concepts, except for continuity of affine transformations. I’d say there is some relationship between affine transformations and **differentiability.**